# Quickest route to a CI solution?

Tags: continuous-integration

We use the following tools internally

- Visual Studio/TFS on-premise for Source Control and as an ALM
- TeamCity to build nuget packages and binaries
- Octopus Deploy to deploy the nuget packages to environments

We want to get to the point where we can run off a build in TeamCity, and have a suite of automated tests run against the build. Our current thinking is that we deploy from Octopus to an Automation environment, and then call some PowerShell as a deployment step which calls Microsoft's Test Runner to run the automation tests against that environment.

Is this the best avenue to pursue? Or are there better ways of achieving CI without having to use Lab Manager etc...?

Should we be looking at Test Hub? If so, can that be hooked up to TeamCity build processes?

Comment: Voting for closing, as this question seems more suitable for https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JoãoFarias while devops may already have this information, I believe it's relevant here as well. SQA is alway going to have a certain amount of crossover with other stack exchange sites.

Comment: I don't know that it's quickest, but if you are working with TFS2017 or above for your on prem environment, you may be able to use the TFS build/release process for your CI. This does not require Lab Manager etc. I haven't looked, but there may be TeamCity and Octopus Deploy integrations for TFS that can be used.

Comment: @JoãoFarias I don't have a strong opinion about having CI questions here, but there are now 89 questions about CI and it is relevant to some degree

Answer (score 1):

What we do is:

1. Create a TFS project that packages the test scripts and push to octopus server, and trigger an octopus build
2. The octopus build will deploy the test scripts and extract to target, execute the power shell script to run the script, and send emails if something fails
3. We call the above octopus project through "Deploy a release" step from the actual project deployement

Comment: Thanks @PDHide, I'll take a look.

Comment: Here instead of calling the PowerShell script from the actual project we call it in from a different project.

Comment: This allow cleaner variable declaration , and also you can pass down variables from parent project to your child test project when needed